# Can I create my own browser window for my PHP application?

Tags: php, user-interface, browser, web-applications, desktop-application

I created an application written in PHP for my client. Since it's stored in a remote server, he needs to open the browser and type the address to open the application.

Since he is not much of a technical person, he reluctant to go through those steps. (Open browser.. etc) And use a third party browser.

**So, is there anyway, that I can create my own small desktop application as an interface or window and include a browser extension or something with a fixed address to my PHP application..**

So, that my client just needs to click on that icon and it opens the particular app straight away..

Comment: Why not use a browser/desktop short-cut ? What you're trying to do will probably be a lot more work than your actual PHP application.

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/create-desktop-shortcut-website

Comment: Yes it could be used, but it doesn't give any uniqueness for the app. That's why I'm worried.

Comment: You can always rename the shortcut. That's probably the best option in your case.

Comment: Or change the icon of the shortcut maybe: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-icon-shortcut (assuming your client is on Windows)

Comment: There was https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism from Mozilla that allowed you to create a desktop like app from a web app, but that was discontinued a while back.

Answer (score -2):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are tying to do, but if you are looking to create a desktop icon that links to your application, you can create a shortcut on your desktop and set the location of the shortcut to the URL of your web application. Double clicking the shortcut will then open your web page using the default browser on your machine